# Cannot import PyTorch/XLA for using TPU in CoLab with ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, google-colaboratory, tpu

I want to use TPU to run a PyTorch program on Google Colab, and I installed PyTorch/XLA in my CoLab notebook by using this code:

```
!pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 torch==1.12.0 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/tpuvm/torch_xla-1.12-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Then, I successfully imported pytorch by
`import torch`.

But, when I tried to import torch_xla by using `import torch_xla`, I got this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7fe098b5b807> in <module>
----> 1 import torch_xla

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch_xla/__init__.py in <module>
     99 from ._patched_functions import _apply_patches
    100 from .version import __version__
--> 101 import _XLAC
    102 
    103 

ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch_xla/lib/libxla_computation_client.so)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The version of Python is Python 3.8.15.

I thought that perhaps downgrading the Python version to Python 3.7 might help, but is there a solution that does not need to downgrade the Python version?

Answer (score 0):

`https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/tpuvm/torch_xla-1.12-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl` doesn't look like the correct colab wheel.

If you plan to run the colab on TPU, can you try the command `!pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 torch==1.13.0 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/colab/torch_xla-1.13-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl` instead?

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: torch_xla-1.13-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
!pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 torch==2.0.0 torchvision==0.15.1 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/colab/torch_xla-2.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
```

on Colab with Python 3.10 version, it works